# ¿Cómo recoger todos los resultados de una operación y sacar el total?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array de objetos que es una cesta de la compra, en la cual el usuario introduce el nombre del producto, su precio y cantidad: hasta ahí todo bien. El problema que tengo es que solo saca el total de los dos primeros objetos introducidos al array, a partir del tercero lo único que imprime por pantalla es su nombre porque sus valores no los contempla, por ejemplo he puesto tres valores que tenían de valor `precio_unitario=2 * cantidad=2`, todo eso repetido 3 veces debería dar como resultado el total de valor 12 no, pues solo me saca 8. Aquí dejo el código entero para que puedan verlo ustedes mismos, y en un comentario en el codigo indico donde creo que esta el problema

Aquí dejo el código del cual hablo en cuestión:

```
var compra = new Array();

function mercado(producto, precio_unidad, cantidad) {

  this.producto = producto;
  this.precio_unidad = precio_unidad;
  this.cantidad = cantidad;

}

var numproductos = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos productos vas a comprar"));
for (let i = 0; i < numproductos; i++) {
  var compras = comprando();
  compra.push(compras);
}

console.log(compras);

function comprando() {

  var comprobar;
  do {
    comprobar = true;
    var producto = prompt("Insertar el nombre del producto que quieres comprar").toUpperCase();

    compra.forEach(element => {
      if (element.producto == producto) {
        alert("Producto repetido");
        comprobar = false;
      }
    });
  } while (comprobar == false);
  var precio_unidad = parseFloat(prompt("Precio del producto"));
  var cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos productos vas a introducir en tu cesta"));

  var comprar_realizada = new mercado(producto, precio_unidad, cantidad);

  return comprar_realizada;

}
//aqui en esta parte de abajo es donde empieza el problema
var producto_total;

compra.forEach(element => {

  document.write(element.producto + "<br>");
  //Solo quita [i]  
  producto_total = element.cantidad * element.precio_unidad;

  total = producto_total + producto_total;


  console.log(producto_total);


});
document.write("El total es: " + total + "<br>");
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Este tipo de variables se les conoce como [acumuladores](https://www.google.com/search?q=variables+acumuladoras&oq=variables+acumu&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30l9.3524j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tenes un error en el total a pagar debido a que solo calculas de la
> forma que lo codificas el total para uno de los objetos te agregue
> unos console.log te pueden ayudar a interpretar como se ejecuta

[podes probar el codigo en este link](https://js.do/)

> También podes escribir menos código y mas legible usando otras
> funciones para recorrer arrays for ... of,map() y para filtrar datos
> filter()

[Métodos Arrays](https://es.javascript.info/array-methods)

```js
var compra = new Array();

function mercado(producto, precio_unidad, cantidad) {

  this.producto = producto;
  this.precio_unidad = precio_unidad;
  this.cantidad = cantidad;

}

var numproductos = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos productos vas a comprar"));
for (let i = 0; i < numproductos; i++) {
  var compras = comprando();
  compra.push(compras);
}
   console.log('compra:',compra)
console.log(compras);

function comprando() {

  var comprobar;
  do {
    comprobar = true;
    var producto = prompt(" nombre del producto").toUpperCase();

    compra.forEach(element => {
      if (element.producto == producto) {
        alert("Producto repetido");
        comprobar = false;
      }
    });
  } while (comprobar == false);
  var precio_unidad = parseFloat(prompt("Precio "));
  var cantidad = parseInt(prompt("cantidad"));

  var comprar_realizada = new mercado(producto, precio_unidad, cantidad);

  return comprar_realizada;

}
//acá la correcion
var producto_total=0;

compra.forEach(element => {
console.log('compra element',element);
  document.write(element.producto+'-->' +'Paga:',element.cantidad * element.precio_unidad,"<br>");
   
  console.log('element.cantidad :',element.cantidad ,'element.precio_unidad:',element.precio_unidad)
  producto_total += (element.cantidad * element.precio_unidad);
 





});
document.write("El total es: " +  producto_total + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Al aplicar [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) sobre tu arreglo (que es de objetos) te devuelve un objeto:

```js
var compra = new Array();

function mercado(producto, precio_unidad, cantidad) {

  this.producto = producto;
  this.precio_unidad = precio_unidad;
  this.cantidad = cantidad;

}

function comprando() {

  var comprobar;
  do {
    comprobar = true;
    var producto = prompt("Insertar el nombre del prudcto que quieres comprar");

    compra.forEach(element => {
      if (element.producto == producto) {
        alert("Producto repetido");
        comprobar = false;
      }
    });
  } while (comprobar == false);
  var precio_unidad = parseFloat(prompt("Precio del producto"));
  var cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos productos vas a comprar"));

  var comprar_realizada = new mercado(producto, precio_unidad, cantidad);

  return comprar_realizada;

}

var numproductos = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos productos vas a comprar"));
for (let i = 0; i < numproductos; i++) {
  var compras = comprando();
  compra.push(compras);
}

console.log(compras);
var producto_total;

compra.forEach(element => {
  document.write(element.producto + "<br>");
  //Solo quita [i]  
  producto_total = element.cantidad * element.precio_unidad;
  total = +producto_total;
  
  document.write(total);
  
});
```

Comment: Vale, ya lo he entendido muchas gracias

Comment: Tal vez hablo desde la ignorancia, pero [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) no devuelve un objeto... devuelve `undefined`, de acuerdo a la documentación a la que haces referencia.

Comment: Error de sintaxis mío. Quise decir: "Al aplicar `forEach` sobre tu arreglo (que es de objetos) te devuelve un objeto. Edito mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de hacer:

```
variable = variable + otro_valor
```

mas resumidamente, es usando `+=`:

```
variable += otro_valor
```

ejemplo:

```js
let total_parcial = 100;

total_parcial += 20; // <-- equivalente a total_parcial = total_parcial + 20;

console.log("El total es:",total_parcial)
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra manera de realizarlo al trabajar con un array de objetos es usando la [función reductora](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (puedes verificar la [compatibilidad de esta función](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#compatibilidad_con_navegadores) en tu navegador).

```js
var productos = [
  { precio: 25, cantidad: 4 }, // <- 25 * 4 = 100
  { precio: 30, cantidad: 2 }  // <- 30 * 2 = 60 
];

const reducer = function(total, item) {
    return total + (item.precio * item.cantidad);
}

var total = productos.reduce(reducer, 0);

document.write(total); // <- Se espera como resultado 160
```

El argumento `total` en la función `reducer`, corresponde al `acumulador`, es decir, *el total acumulado por cada producto*.

El argumento `item`, corresponde al `valorActual` que está siendo procesado en el array para sumarlo al `acumulador`. Esto sería *cada objeto en el array*.

Al llamar el método `reduce` en tu array, se pasa `0` como `valorInicial`, de esta forma, el `acumulador` iniciará en 0.

---

Para resumir la función anterior, puedes usar una [expresión de función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var productos = [
  { precio: 25, cantidad: 4 }, // <- 25 * 4 = 100
  { precio: 30, cantidad: 2 }  // <- 30 * 2 = 60 
];

var total = productos.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.precio * item.cantidad), 0);

document.write(total); // <- Se espera como resultado 160
```

Comment: Hola buenas, he cambiado la pregunta y el problema que tengo ahora, ya que me han surgido nuevos fallos.